# Why is in-place mutation represented with `IO`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, language-agnostic, mutation, in-place

Why are mutable data structures and other mutability represented using `IO` in functional languages? I'm looking at e.g. Haskell's [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) or Idris' [`IOArray`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/base_docs/docs/Data.IOArray.html).

I don't think I mean this as a historical or design question. I don't quite understand why `IO` is suitable for mutation - or rather, why mutation becomes pure when encapsulated in `IO`.

Comment: Most likely this would be better fit for https://langdev.stackexchange.com/ or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ... Historical/design questions usually considered too broad for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks. I don't think I mean it as a historical or design question. I don't quite understand why `IO` is suitable for mutation - or rather, why mutation becomes pure when encapsulated in `IO`. Historical/design suggests that there was also a choice in the matter, which I wasn't aware of

Comment: There are no mutations from the user's point of view. If you had a `data Op = Assign Int | Output` and a `program = [Assign 1, Assign 2, Output, Assign 42, Output]` then you could undoubtedly create a function that takes `program` and outputs `[2,42]`. Does that mean `Assign 2` has a side effect? No. Does it mean `Output` returns a different value every time? No. But still, if you create a list of them you can still somehow kinda-sorta program as if you have mutable state. Monads are basically fancy ways of creating (potentially infinite) sequences of such steps.

Comment: @joel, I think your follow-up comment is key to understanding what you're asking here, so I've copied it into your question.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to represent them with `IO`. It's possible to do them in [`ST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) instead. But you *can* obviously represent them with `IO`, where any dirty side effect can be achieved. So if you're working in `IO` anyway, it's easiest to just do the mutations there too, this way you don't need to put any worry on welding different monads together. If you're *not* already working in `IO`, you should use `ST` however.

Comment: I'm familiar with pretending to mutate variables with the state monad, but from the `ST` docs it looks like this is primarily a "mutation" monad. Is it any different from a state monad that's compiled to in-place mutation?

Comment: Yes, it's different.  The `ST` monad supports compiler primitives that mutate memory locations (see the code for `STRef`).  As far as I know, the `State` monad is never compiled to code that mutates state in memory, at least not with GHC.  It would be better to think of `ST` as "real" mutation, with `IO` = `ST` + I/O operations.

Comment: @joel Try to implement `newSTRef` using `State` instead of `ST` (i.e. `newStateRef :: YourChoiceOfContextIDon'tMind s => State s (StateRef a)`) and you will see that they are quite different indeed.

Comment: @joel In particular, even **if** some `State` computation were sometimes optimised to execute by mutation in place, that would be almost accidental. The API of `State` just deals in values, and indeed it's quite valid for earlier state values to still have references after "changes", so it obviously can't *always* be implemented as mutation. `ST` has an API that explicitly deals in references to mutable storage; you *specify* the mutations, they're not an accidental effect of optimisations.

Comment: this is super useful to know. I'd long assumed people were talking about state when they mentioned `ST`, given `ST`ate. I actually could do with `ST` in my work

Comment: I've just notice that Idris' `STRef` and `ST` are think wrappers round `IORef` and `IO` respectively. Is that an implementation detail, do you know, or is `ST`/`STRef` is just a reframing of  `IO`/`IORef`?

Comment: @joel Implementation detail. You can't (or aren't supposed to be able to) actually do IO in `ST`. `runST` is supposed to be a pure function.